# Multiple requests with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape the following URLs, however, I need to create two different requests, one for properties for sale and one for rent, as the URL differs.

When I run the code I have I am only able to parse the properties that are for sale ('propbay')  and not for rent ('rentbay'). And I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the second request.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import re
import requests


class ProbRentBaySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'prob_rent_bay'
    start_urls = [
    'https://www.propbay.co.za/for-sale-property/residential/za/western_cape/7',
    'https://www.rentbay.co.za/to-rent-property/residential/za/western_cape/7'
    ]

    headers = {
    'authority': 'www.propbay.co.za',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="86", "\\"Not\\\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': '_ga=GA1.3.1758254184.1598490742; ASP.NET_SessionId=v1muaskigrgnn40m42lsqzct; __RequestVerificationToken=AIEv13vh8ksXZeG6Tf_o-vLCscKt7sYKJjwB0kz0CfqmCe8ZpYRQQdGk2BnN095p2A6wlFf7o_lVYyxe1Jro-I5vHE01; _gid=GA1.3.900892753.1605696808',
}
    headers2 = {
    'authority': 'www.rentbay.co.za',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="86", "\\"Not\\\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=rexgmrrgju10aw4rirulzrmk; _ga=GA1.3.225479946.1606814269; __RequestVerificationToken=az6ZATA2H0dJfBQ6KuwDwz39XGSiSuIjc4iZwRT8BGSD2surYfA6iOmkIQk2p835G51hYqJd5FFoiSQYsvx-V3Ndx6s1; _gid=GA1.3.1154633027.1607081144; _gat_gtag_UA_7413963_2=1',
}

    base_url_sale = ['https://www.propbay.co.za/Property/ListByCityAjax?city=Cape%20Town&province=western%20cape&cityCode=199041&category=3&page=',
                    'https://www.propbay.co.za/Property/ListByCityAjax?city=Milnerton&province=western%20cape&cityCode=199014&category=3&page=' ]
    base_url_rent = ['https://www.rentbay.co.za/Property/ListByCityAjax?city=Cape%20Town&province=western%20cape&cityCode=199041&category=3&page=',
                    'https://www.rentbay.co.za/Property/ListByCityAjax?city=Milnerton&province=western%20cape&cityCode=199014&category=3&page=' ]

    def parse(self,response):     
        for page in range(2, 8):# specify page range you would like to scrape data for
            for link in self.base_url_sale:
                next_page = link + str(page)
                response = requests.get(url=next_page, headers=self.headers)
                for product in response.json()['Data']['Suburbs']:
                    area_url = 'https://www.propbay.co.za'+ product['FriendlyUrl']
                yield scrapy.Request(area_url,callback=self.parse_sale)

        for page2 in range(2, 8):# specify page range you would like to scrape data for
            for link2 in self.base_url_rent:
                next_page2 = link2 + str(page2)
                response2 = requests.get(url=next_page2, headers=self.headers2)
                for product2 in response2.json()['Data']['Suburbs']:
                    area_url_2 = 'https://www.rentbay.co.za'+ product2['FriendlyUrl']
                yield scrapy.Request(area_url_2,callback=self.parse_rent)

    def parse_sale(self, response):
        # follow links to property pages
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="u-text-uppercase"]/@href').getall():
            follow_link = 'https://www.propbay.co.za'+ href
            yield response.follow(follow_link, self.parse_property)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="btnNext"]/@href'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_sale)

    def parse_rent(self, response):
        # follow links to property pages
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="u-text-uppercase"]/@href').getall():
            follow_link = 'https://www.rentbay.co.za'+ href
            yield response.follow(follow_link, self.parse_property)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="btnNext"]/@href').getall():
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_rent)

    def parse_property(self, response):

        title = response.css('span.u-text-capitalize::text').get()
        bedrooms = response.xpath('//span[contains(text(), "Bedrooms")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()
        bedrooms = bedrooms.split()[0] if bedrooms is not None else None
...
```

Edited code:
I have tried to make separate parsing functions, however, I am only getting rental properties, not sure how to get also the properties for sale.

```
   def parse(self,response):
        for page in range(2, 8):# specify page range you would like to scrape data for
            for link in self.base_url_sale:
                next_page = link + str(page)
                response = requests.get(url=next_page, headers=self.headers)
                for product in response.json()['Data']['Suburbs']:
                    area_url = 'https://www.propbay.co.za'+ product['FriendlyUrl']
                    yield scrapy.Request(area_url,callback=self.parse_rent)

    
    def parse_rent(self, response):
        for page2 in range(2, 8):# specify page range you would like to scrape data for
            for link2 in self.base_url_rent:
                next_page2 = link2 + str(page2)
                response = requests.get(url=next_page2, headers=self.headers2)
                for product2 in response.json()['Data']['Suburbs']:
                    item = dict()
                    area_url_2 = 'https://www.rentbay.co.za'+ product2['FriendlyUrl']
                    yield scrapy.Request(area_url_2,callback=self.parse_all)

    def parse_all(self, response):
        # follow links to property pages
        for href in response.xpath('//a[@class="u-text-uppercase"]/@href').getall():
            follow_link = 'https://www.propbay.co.za'+ href
            yield response.follow(follow_link, self.parse_property)

        # follow pagination links
        for href in response.xpath('//*[@id="btnNext"]/@href'):
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_all)
```

Comment: Should `yield scrapy.Request(area_url_2,callback=self.parse_rent)` be inside the preceding `for product2 in...` loop? Seems like it should be?

Comment: @harada it just keeps looping forever if I do that

Comment: Maybe try appending all the `area_url_2` that are produced to a list, then yielding the request from that list. I'm not sure why it loops forever in the first method I suggested because there should be a finite number of products in `response2.json()['Data']['Suburbs']`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to override start_requests and specify different callbacks for each url and then split you `parse()` logic into those two methods. Else you can at least have an if check on url before looping over either propbay or rentbay part. For now the responses of both urls are being treated the same way in your parse. So may be first time the request is incorrect as your response is for propbay but second time when it was correct it is filtered by the dupefilter.

For an instant fix you can try adding `don't_filter=True` to your requests in parse method.

Comment: When I add dont_filter=True I get a lot of redirecting requests. I have tried to write separate functions for parsing as suggested, but I'm only getting now rental properties. Any suggestion on what am I doing wrong now? I have added the edited code above in the question. Thank you! @AbbasMaalikWattoo